# Joining Based On An Aggregate Function

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables that look like the following

**Table 1**

```
Name      Status          Code
----------------------------------------
pop       AB              CO-Completed
pop       AG              FF-Open
```

**Table 2**

```
ID     Code
--------------
1       CO
2       FF
```

I am attempting to write a query that returns the status from table 1 and id from table given a code from table 2

I attempted to do this but I am looking at something wrong....

```
select * from Table1 a
join Table2 b
on a.SUBSTRING('Code',1,2)=b.Code
where b.ID = '1'
```

I want the return set to be

```
ID      Code     Status
-------------------------
1       CO       AB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have single quotes around `CODE`, so you have a string constant.  Remove those and the code will work.  This method would more commonly be written with the `left()` function:

```
select *
from Table1 a join
     Table2 b
     on left(a.code, 2) = b.Code
where b.ID = 1;
```

Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Although they can be used in other contexts (depending on the database), they cause problems as you have just discovered.